# Problems after upgrading from 20.10

Tags: bluetooth, ubuntu-mate, 21.04, software-boutique

So recently, I decided  to head back to Ubuntu MATE from Ubuntu, and so far pretty good.
I upgraded from 20.10 because it reached it's end of life.. but after I did that I experienced some problems.

For example, Bluetooth doesn't work (it works with Raspberry Pi OS, RetroPie, and Windows 11), but Ubuntu-based distributions fail. (It seemed to work in 20.10 however...)
Whenever I try to enable it with Bluetooth Manager, it shows up for a split second then then vanishes from the task bar.

Another problem I'm having is I can't run `ubuntu-mate-welcome` or Software Boutique. Whenever I tried running it through the terminal, I receive this:

```
root@aC-ubmPi400:~# ubuntu-mate-welcome --boutique
/ not root-owned 1000:1000
```

`Linux aC-ubmPi400 5.11.0-1016-raspi #17-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Thu Jul 29 15:33:06 UTC 2021 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux`

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="21.04 (Hirsute Hippo)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 21.04"
VERSION_ID="21.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=hirsute
UBUNTU_CODENAME=hirsute
```

I'm on a Raspberry Pi 400 with Ubuntu MATE 21.04 running on a 2TB HDD

[image]

That's the terminal input, the same results happen if I run the launcher from the desktop.

Comment: The failed launch attempt was `/ not root-owned 1000:1000`

Comment: Edited my question, done

Comment: Well, the obvious questions would seem to be: Why is that application not owned by root? Did you change it's ownership? What happens if you change it's ownership back to what it should be?

Comment: FYI, the upgrade path is no longer supported once a version goes EOL. It's expected that you upgrade before the EOL date.  Upgrading every 6 months for standard releases is not for everyone and it might be better to use a LTS release since you have three years to upgrade after the next LTS instead of only 3 months to upgrade upon release of a new standard release.  See: [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)